# If vectors can be shifted any where in space then how do we say that only some part of space has a field eg: Electric field.

Tags: vectors, 3d

I do not understand the property of invariancy(Property of shifting a vector anywhere in space keeping magnitude and direction fixed) of a vector and it seems very ambiguous to me. Please help me understand this concept.
And how are we able to use Vectors in our calculations of Cartesian systems in 3D, a line in 3D is fixed but a line vector can be shifted anywhere?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by invariancy?

Comment: The property where we can shift a vector anywhere in space keeping its magnitude and direction fixed

Comment: Might be worth looking at free vectors and localised vectors

Comment: I did I just don't understand where we apply which